# Disregard sheet with single text field using escape key

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nstextfield

So this is my setup:

A trivial `NSWindow` with a single `NSTextField` for user entry plus an '***Accept***' type `NSButton`.

The window is displayed for my document window as a sheet using [`beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAlert/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:)

I'd like to close the sheet when the user presses the escape key, however all I get is the funny system sound telling me it's not really expecting an escape key at that point.

There are several similar questions suggesting we should just check for [`cancelOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/cancelOperation:) somewhere in the responder chain. Thing is, my window controller (for the window/dialog in the sheet) **isn't even in the responder chain** when I'm checking it in the debugger.

For the sheet displayed in the way aforementioned the responder chain is still all about my document window. Weird.

So any hints how to properly hook up to either [`cancelOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/cancelOperation:) or the Escape key would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try in the debugger and see whether the cancelOperation: or even keyDown: methods are hit in your NSResponder subclass (e.g. your view controller/window controller)?

Answer (score 3):

Since your sheet can be cancelled, you should probably add a Cancel button to it to make that possibility clear to the user.  If you do that, and set the keyboard shortcut of that Cancel button to the escape key in IB, then it ought to Just Work.  I think it is important that the name of the button is actually "Cancel", though; I recall reading that AppKit does some special glue magic behind the scenes based on that button name.

And by the way, it seems like your window controller should be in the responder chain, assuming it is an actual `NSWindowController` set up in the proper way; see Apple's doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2).  Not sure why the debugger indicates that it isn't, but it should be, as far as I can tell.  If it really isn't, that might indicate something more deeply wrong with how you're setting up the sheet.  I'm not sure about that, though, since I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I guess the question isn't about how to hook up a cancel button but how to handle the escape key in general in this setup

Comment: My point is that AppKit, I believe, has special handling code for the escape key inside sheets, and using a Cancel button – besides being good user interface design if a panel is in fact cancellable – will get you the benefits of that special handling code for free.  Swim with the current, not against it.

Comment: @SteveM, it seems to me that I have answered your question.  If so, please accept the answer.  If not, please clarify why not.